# Python string eval failing on empty items in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

```
import ast 

s = "[0,1,,,2]"
d = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

I have a string with blank items in a list that I need convert to a list.  Is there any library that can handle lists like this?  The actual list I have is a bit more complex with nested lists so a manual parser would preferably not be the route I take.

Comment: Does this string follow a known syntax (e.g., JSON ... but of course this isn't)? What are the rules? Is this always a list of integers where splitting on the comma would work?

Comment: @tdelaney It's a javascript list.

Comment: What value do you want those empty commas to produce?  If it's None, for example, then replacing `,,` with `,None,` would make it valid syntax.  (You may need to do a regex replace of `,\s*,` if there may be whitespace between commas.)

Comment: Have you looked at [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)? You could remove the "[" and "]" and split by commas. You could then proceed to remove all empty values in the list with a for loop. You could also run this recursively for nested loops.

Comment: What do you mean by "blank items"? What should end up in the resulting list? What possibilities are there for the items? If they are strings, will they be quoted per Python's ordinary syntax? The problem needs to be specified more before it is possible to write code. More importantly: **why** do you have this string? Have you considered fixing the process that creates that string, so that you get something easier to work with? (perhaps something in a standard format, such as JSON?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel https://controlc.com/a306bc9d It's a javascript array.  And no, I can't modify the data, it comes as a string like this.

Comment: @asdad23 why should the result be? Javascript arrays are not like Python lists (or like arrays, for that matter they are basically specialized hashmaps)

Comment: In any case, there may be Javascript parsers you could use that are available in Python, you'd still have to decide how you'd want that string to be evaluate though, as in, what the resulting value would be

Comment: I bumped into js2py via [geeksforgeeks.com](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-javascript-from-python/) and it worked for your example string. Worth a look. `python3 -m pip install js2py`. Then `js2py.eval_js("[0,1,,,2]")`. See if it works for your more complicated source.

Answer (score 1):

empty blanks ",," is not a valid json string or python.

your best bet is to covert this into a valid json ",null," or python ",None," and then try to evaluate it.

```
def replace(s):
   s=s.replace(',,',',null,');
   s=s.replace(',,',',null,');
   return s

a='[1,2,,,3]'
b='[2,3,4,,,,5]'
```

This would yield

```
>>> json.loads(replace(a))
[1, 2, None, None, 3]
>>> json.loads(replace(b))
[2, 3, 4, None, None, None, 5]
```

Comment: although this is not a clean solution. a recommended approach will be to send valid JSON object from javascript and parse it python

Comment: If the list has strings which themselves have embedded commas, this could fail.

Comment: yeah agreed, it won't work on complex / nested structure. hence i highly recommend for user to switch to a proper JSON format for data transmission between frontend and backend.